# Swift can't get Facebook username

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0

I use the lastest Facebook SDK in swift. My problem is when I try to pass my Facebook name into a variable. There is my code :

```
func returnUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            // This variable is declared under my class declaration
            self.userFacebook = result.valueForKey("name") as! String
            println(self.userFacebook) //it's works, my Facebook name appear
        }
    })
}
```

But, when I try to use my variable "userFacebook" outsite of this function (returnUserData), the result is "nil". 
I don't understand why my variable is set only in the function and not in my class.

Thanks

Comment: _“I don't understand why my variable is set only in the function and not in my class”_ – most likely because the request is made in an asynchronous fashion.

Comment: Do you know an synchronous fashion??

Answer (score 1):

You pass parameter request what data is get for example get name.

request parameter like this

```
["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]
```

Try this code :

```
@IBAction func btnFBLoginPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    var fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager .logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], handler: { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            var fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    })
}

func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                println(result)
                println(result["name"])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Same problem, your code just do a Facebook connection and get data with parameters. 
When I call getFBUserData() function,  if I do a println(self.usernameFacebook) just return me "nil"

Comment: The println(result) works fine, but I can't get the value of result["fisrt_name"] outside of the function getFBUserData() event if I do "self.usernameFacebook = result["fisrt_name"] as! String".
If I try to println(self.usernameFacebook) after I called getFBUserData() in my viewDidLoad() funtion, it returns "nil"

Comment: Hum ok, and did you know a solution to pass value outsite of this asynchronous function?

Comment: Did you have a code example to explain that, I don't really understand?

Comment: where to use facebook data? @Michal

Comment: How to store and use the dictionary data from Facebook

Comment: my question is where to print or use you facebook data in app? you print data in label? @Michal

Comment: I want to use Facebook data in an another ViewController to print user Facebook name.

Comment: So you direct Store data in Dictionary and after to move you other Controller. @Michal

Comment: `if (error == nil){// store data in dictionary 
self .performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToDetail", sender: nil)
 }` like this way

Comment: Thanks you for help ;)

Comment: `var dict : [String:String] = [String:String]()
 dict = result` like this way you store dict data, but i not sore this proper code or not because i don't know swift very well. welcome @Michal